# macvtap interface associated with a VM on a host cannot ping host eno1 IP

Tags: tap

VM interface XML config has source device pointing to the host management interface eno1 that is configured with IP of 10.134.159.48/24




When the VM is launched a macvtap interface gets created for the VM. I have configured VMs ip as 10.134.159.251/24 with gateway as 10.134.159.48 (eno1 IP). Ping in both directions (from VM to eno1 and eno1 to VM IP) fail.
The host OS is centos 7.
tcpdump on the host eno1 shows ARP request from the VM IP, but its not replying back to the request. Not able to figure out the problem. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This happens because macvtap works in a way that prevents host and guest seeing each other. You can look for possible solutions in https://superuser.com/questions/349253/guest-and-host-cannot-see-each-other-using-linux-kvm-and-macvtap

Comment: https://www.furorteutonicus.eu/2013/08/04/enabling-host-guest-networking-with-kvm-macvlan-and-macvtap/ is even better article for this issue.